# Performant data compression of 40,000 bytes

Tags: java, network-programming, compression

I have seen data compression libaries around the internet like *zlib* and *lzo*. But I am not sure about the best way to compress 40,000 bytes(they are in an `byte[][](x,y = color)`), I need to get it down to something like 200 bytes but there is a catch: this can not take too long, maybe 1/40 of a sec at most.

I am unsure if this is even possible and what would be the best option to take. I also would need the output to be in a `byte[]` meaning I would need to lose the second dimension of the array and be able to gain it again when the decompression happens. I do not want to save any data to file as I am going to be sending it to a client and when I send data I just have to give it a `byte[]` and it does all the rest. (I can not change the method of sending data to the client.) Thanks for any help.

EDIT: i dont mind if i lose data, just as long as that data issent the same data every time it is sent as there will be am update sent with new info every 1/4 of a sec, i am not sending an image so what you are saying about png dossent realy help as i am making up the colors on the server program (not reading from a file). hope this helps.

Comment: 40K->200 ??  If the image is any more complex than, say, pac-man, you may be in trouble.

Comment: Two things to clarify: a) how much do you care about losing some accuracy? and b) what do you know about the distribution / patterns in the data?

Comment: If this requirement is part of some tender / contract bail out now unless they expect the Pacman images Martin mentioned.

Comment: i have edited the question with more info like it is not a file being read.

Comment: You have a 2D array of colors but it's not an image? What is it, then?

Comment: The achievable Compression rate depends heavily on the structure of your data. With general approaches you most likely won't be successful with your given requirements. However if one can make assumptions about the structure of your data (e.g. inherent logic) maybe a custom compression algorithm may solve your problem. Als think about shemes where you only sent updates of data in case the client has a previous version of your data.

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally, there's no general compression scheme which can achieve significant compression for *every* input of arbitrary data in a lossless way. You can either live with the possibility of getting more data than you started with, or data loss... it's your choice. Trying to get the data down to 1/20 of the original is a pretty tall order in general though.

Given that this is image data, you probably shouldn't be looking at general purpose compression routines - instead, look at image formats such as JPEG, PNG etc. Aside from anything else, some image formats have "quality" options which allow you to achieve greater compression at the cost of poorer fidelity. Still, 200 bytes really isn't much information...

I would focus on getting a viable result (small enough, but with good enough quality) before you focus on the performance side of things. When you've got something working at all, you can see whether it's fast enough - but there's no point in working hard to make something fast if it doesn't meet your initial requirements.

The 1D/2D side of things is likely to drop out if you use image-based compression. If you go for some kind of custom scheme, it's easy enough to store the length of one dimension and infer the other. This is basically the least problematic part of your requirements :)

Comment: Your first sentence is inaccurate: many effective lossless compression schemes exist, assuming you are able to exploit your knowledge about the distribution of the data (i.e. it is not something like pure random noise)

Comment: @mikera I don't know of any which are lossless AND will not increase in size in the worst case.

Comment: +1 You can limit the increase to a single byte with the right encoding.

Comment: @mikera: If you're limiting the set of valid inputs, then you don't really have that many bytes of information, effectively. If you *don't* limit the set of valid inputs, then it's pretty clear that you can't always compress... you'd have more potential inputs than potential outputs.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: A single bit, presumably: attempt a particular (known) compression scheme. If it manages to make it smaller by more than a bit, then write out a 1 bit and then the compressed data. Otherwise, write out a 0 bit and the uncompressed data :)

Comment: @JonSkeet It's a bit hard to add a single bit to a stream/file. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Indeed. But from an information theory perspective... :)

Comment: You might be able to avoid increasing the size if the data has known headers. (e.g. it's an imagine type or ASCII text) Using a different header only if the compression has been used could be an option.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: But in that case it goes back to "not all inputs are valid" - you're basically limiting the set of inputs to less than 40,000 * 8 independent bits.

Comment: i have edited the question with more info like it is not a file being read.

Comment: @user1691444: I never suggested that it *is* a file. Your question is basically too vague to answer in any more detail... particularly as you say that you're sending a rectangular array of colours, but for some reason that *isn't* an image?

Comment: i am not reading the rectangles from a file(may that be png, jpeg etc), you answer talks about png quality settings. the colors are randomly made and are placed into the array at runtime.

Comment: @user1691444: But you can still *regard* that as an image, and then compress it with PNG compression. The settings would be set at *compression* time - not reading the image. Again, nothing in my answer requires you to be reading from a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't always compress 40000 bytes to 200 bytes without losing data. However, if your data is a computer-generated image with few colors, this is not too unlikely to produce 200 bytes or less:

1) Feed the data to a PNG compression library.

The best possible compression takes some time, but you can save a lot of time by sacrificing the compression level slightly. If your library is OptiPNG, then a level of 2 or 3 might be a good balance between speed and compression.

2) Since you know the image size, drop the header and all other chunks that you can recover on the receiving side. All you should be left with is the `IDAT` chunk. Even then, you can strip the first few bits (the chunk header) off of it).

When decompressing:

1) prepend the `IHDR` chunk (known in advance) and (if you use a palette) the `PLTE` chunk (also known in advance), and the header of the `IDAT` chunk. Append the `IEND` chunk.

2) feed this data to a PNG decompression library.

The `.png` file format is well documented. You can use [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.png#.22Chunks.22_within_the_file) as your starting point.

Comment: i have edited the question with more info like it is not a file being read.

Comment: @user1691444 I never claimed it was a file. I only assumed that it was a 2D array of colors that's supposed to be easily compressible (i.e. an image)

Answer (score 0):

To check if what your're trying to do is *theoretically* possible, take one or more samples of input images and calculate the [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) (or ["Shannon Entropy"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_entropy)) for that data. This will give at least an estimation of how much information (entropy) there actually is in your data.

If the entropy in one input image calculates to more than 200*8 bits there probably is *no* general, lossless compression scheme which can do the desired compression *on single images*.

If you have a sequence of images, however, you may possibly only encode the differences from one image to the next and achieve *on average* your target bandwidth; see for example common video codecs.

Maybe also have a read-up on ["Source coding"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression).

Comment: There is no entropy calculation that can set a good limit on compressibility.  You just need to try different existing compressors, or write your own to exploit redundancy not exploited by existing compressors.  For this example, consider a random sequence of 32 bytes repeated 1250 times to give 40000 bytes.  A simple entropy calculation (sum of -p log p) would give 25000 bytes.  Much more than 200 bytes.  But any decent compressor would bring this down to less than 200 bytes.

Comment: Indeed, for accurate results of calculating entropy it is crucial that the correct *word size* is used. When dealing, for instance, with data of `long`s calculating the entropy based on the individual `byte`s of the data will usually yield too high an entropy. If, in your example, we would assume the word size to be 32 bytes the entropy calculated would be of the correct value.

Comment: I gave a very simple example.  I can construct another example that would defeat such a calculation, but still compress to less than 200 bytes with any modern lossless compressor.  The point is that it is not possible to come up with an entropy calculation that can set a useful limit, since such a calculation cannot represent all possible models of the data.  See your own comment on source coding, and look up Kolmogorov Complexity, which is not computable.